# Error in Zonal Analysis Stand Alone Script using PyQGIS

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, zonal-statistics

I want to do zonal analysis from QGIS standalone script.For this, I am using following code to run through command line

Following code is save in .bat file.

```
import sys
from qgis.core import *
from qgis.utils import *
from qgis.gui import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
 # Initialize QGIS Application
QgsApplication.setPrefixPath("C:\\OSGeo4W64\\apps\\qgis", True)
app = QgsApplication([], True)
QgsApplication.initQgis()
print 'Hello QGIS1!'
# Add the path to Processing framework
sys.path.append('C:\Users\USERNAME\.qgis2\python\plugins')

# Import and initialize Processing framework
from processing.core.Processing import Processing
Processing.initialize()
import processing

#zonal Analysis

 from qgis.analysis import QgsZonalStatistics

 #specify polygon shapefile vector
 polygonLayer = QgsVectorLayer('F:/test/road_15715.shp','zonepolygons', "ogr") 

# specify raster filename
 rasterFilePath = 'F:/test/abcd.tif'

# usage - QgsZonalStatistics (QgsVectorLayer *polygonLayer, const QString  &rasterFile, const QString &attributePrefix="", int rasterBand=1)

  zoneStat = QgsZonalStatistics (polygonLayer, rasterFilePath,'vi_', 1)
  zoneStat.calculateStatistics(None)


  print 'Zonal Analysis Done!'
```

While using code

```
    zoneStat = QgsZonalStatistics (polygonLayer, rasterFilePath,'vi_', 1)
    zoneStat.calculateStatistics(None)
```

it is working with QGIS Python console but while using in a standalone script, zonal analysis is not done.